# Do I need node.js to use Browserify to bundle my modules?

Tags: javascript, module, browserify

I keep seeing that I need node.js to use Browserify to bundle my modules, but I have no experience with node.js. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Most JS module bundlers are written in JS. And JS on the "server" is mostly run through Node.js.

Comment: Yes and no, respectively. I'm sure there are other ways of bundling modules (Webpack, Rollup, etc.) but if you want to use Browserify (and any of the other ones I listed) you'll need to install Node.js

Comment: can one browserify Browserify? (seriously)